# How to display current location in a map with Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, bing-maps, currentlocation

I want to get current location in Windows Phone 7 and display it on a Bing Map (on WP7) at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get your location from the [GeoCoordinateWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and then add a pushpin at the returned location.

There's an example of how to do this at http://shelastyle.net/blog/windows-phone-7-app-tips-drawing-my-location-on-a-map/

Comment: Hey Matt, the link no longer works. Do you know if the same content is posted elsewhere? I'm looking for it too. Thanks!

Comment: @CodingInCircles if you're still on WP7 try http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/windows-phone-map-control-display-current-location-and-remove-previous-pushpins otherwise see http://www.developer.nokia.com/Blogs/Community/2012/12/03/windows-phone-8-maps-examples-featured-project-of-the-month-december-2012/

Comment: Thanks Matt! :) Any idea where I can get Search Service code from? I've been looking for over a week now and can't find a decent working example. Please refer to my question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019544/using-the-searchservice-from-bing-maps-in-wp7/15022418#comment21181239_15022418. Thanks! :)