# Using the Searchservice from Bing Maps in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-api, bing-maps

I used [this](http://programming4.us/mobile/3478.aspx) to locate an address on Bing Maps on WP7 using the emulator. The site mentions searchservice, which is something I want to try out and implement. However, the method seems to be different, in the sense that the query parameters are different and so is the way to query it. Can anyone help me find resources that give me a (if possible) step-by-step list of how to achieve or implement the searchservice. I have been through the official MSDN pages and they're quite useless. For my needs, at least! Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend to use the Bing Maps REST services, you can find the information about how to use it on the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx

Also, take a look at the official blog where you will be able to find the best practices and good tips to use the REST services using a .Net wrapper:

http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/02/14/bing-maps-rest-service-tips-amp-tricks.aspx

Let us know if you have other difficulties to implement the search service in your Windows Phone application.

Comment: Hi Nicolas! I will surely try it out, but from a preliminary look, it's the same as what I've already seen. They give samples for GeoCodeService, but not for searchservice. It's really annoying and I can't find a working sample anywhere. I will try these links out in more detail and let you know more by tonight. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hey.. Still nothing. The documentation is not clear enough for me to form proper working code. I tried modifying existing code to fit the Search Service API, but nothing is working out. Will accept your answer as there are no others. Thanks! :)

Comment: Could you post your actual code so we can help you to implement it in your application.

Comment: My actual code comes from the sample given in the site mentioned in the question. I just pointed the service reference to the Search Service site and was trying to modify those functions to get it to work. And it's not happening :(